# How can I go to a complete State of angular app

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to access the URL `http://{myapp}/product/car/new`, but I'm getting only the template for state `car.new`.....

I want to load the entire `app` and the `car.new` too

Ps.: It's like copying a URL a link of angular docs: `https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.injector` for example.

Comment: your code structure?

Comment: The focus is how to access the absolute path, not in code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look to [$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location), it will let you get the full url or the params, but it will be wiser for you to show us your code, because we cant know if you already tried this alternative